# Can't find ~/.config?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, config.txt

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/id/Video-Calling-on-Raspberry-Pi-3/):

at one step I'm supposed to change the autostart file with this command:

```
sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

but when I cd into my /home/pi folder (which is equal to `~/`, right?) there is no .config folder:

[image: my /home/pi folder]

I managed to get it done in a workaround, but I'm still wondering, how can I find that .config folder? I've seen that in different tutorials too before...

The workaround was by the way: I found a different autostart file at `etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`, and I put my command in there instead and that worked.

Comment: Any file with a name starting with a full stop is hidden. Use `ls -la` to see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filenames that start with a period (aka. [dotfiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments)) are considered "hidden", and aren't displayed by default by commonplace tools which respect this convention.  Historically, configuration stuff is usually dotfiled. However, the intention is not that you not be able to find or access them (that is done with permissions), nor does it imply they aren't human readable, etc.  It's simply to distinguish them from non-dotfiles.

Anyway, from `man ls`:

> ```
>    -a, --all
>           do not ignore entries starting with .
> ```

Ie., `ls -a ~` should show the directory you are looking for.

Comment: ok thank you, now I managed to get into that folder with `cd -- .config`